# why there is no SUBTRACT and DIVISION function in MS EXCEL..?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

There are so many functions in MS-Excel.

But,why didn't they add the SUBTRACT and DIVISION functions in them..?
If you have any answers please comment..

Comment: You can use `-` for subtraction and `/` for division.

Comment: And excel uses Bodmas ie the order of functions to resolve formulae...

Comment: Imagine those functions were there, how are you planning of using them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because those are Operators, not Functions!

```
Add:      +
Subtract: -
Multiply: *
Divide:   /

Exponent:         ^
Concatenate:      &
```

Furthermore:

Unlike Add or Multiply, they (Subtract and Divide) are not Commutative.  Because `A + B = B + A` and `A * B = B * A`, you can create related Functions (`SUM` and `PRODUCT`) - but `A - B ≠ B - A`, and `A / B ≠ B / A` (with notable exceptions of `0 - 0` or `1 / 1`)

Also, they are not Associative:  `SUM(A, B, C) = A + B + C = (A + B) + C = A + (B + C)`, and `PRODUCT(A, B, C) = A * B * C = (A * B) * C = A * (B * C)`.  However, would `SUBTRACT(A, B, C)` be `A - (B - C)` or `(A - B) - C`?

> `A - (B - C) ≠ (A - B) - C`
>   `A - (B - C) = (A + C) - B`
>   `(A - B) - C = A - (B + C)`